# Code error: 42000. MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, windows

Buen dia estoy instalando un script laravel en un vps y utilice una base de datos remota, cuando ejecute la migracion me arroja el error

```
Code error: 42000.
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1227 Access denied; you 
need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation
```

Alguien me puede explicar que significa? y la forma de solucionarlo

Comment: Es una restricción de privilegios. El usuario con el que intentas hacer esa operación (`RELOAD`) no tiene permiso para hacerla. La solución es otorgarle ese privilegio o conectar con otro usuario que sí los tenga y hacer la operación. Eso sí, debes estar seguro de lo que estás haciendo (me refiero a tu `RELOAD`).

Comment: Buenos Dias Abdiel Hernandez, lo que pasa es que tienes los privilegios bloqueados, debes darle todos los permiso a las carpetas